# Add a tag to jpeg using ExifTool

Tags: metadata, syntax, exiftool

I would like help with terminal syntax code please to add a tag to jpeg files using ExifTool. I want to add general notes to some old scanned jpeg pictures of my ancestors for my kids to be able to easily access in the future. I am using Linux Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding your notes to the `Description` tag.  Your command would look like this:
`exiftool -Description='Some notes' file.jpg`

This command creates backup files.  Add [`-overwrite_original`](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#overwrite_original) to suppress the creation of backup files.  Add [`-r`](https://ExifTool.org/exiftool_pod.html#r-.--recurse) to recurse into subdirectories.

You could also try [hdwolf's jExiftoolGui](https://github.com/hvdwolf/jExifToolGUI/) for a GUI that uses exiftool behind the scenes. It will help deal with the confusing mess that is metadata.

Comment: That works perfectly, just one thing I used exiftool -ImageDescription='Some notes' file.jpg          I can now view the image description notes in the show exif data under the view tab using LXimage viewer. Thank you StarGeek

Comment: `ImageDescription` is the corresponding tag in the EXIF block for `Description`, which is part of the [IPTC Photo Metadata Standard](https://www.iptc.org/std/photometadata/specification/IPTC-PhotoMetadata).  It is not a wildly used tag, though, so not very furture proof.  If you continue to use exiftool, then using the [MWG tags](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/MWG.html), specifically, `-MWG:Descripton='Some Notes'`, would be a better option, as that will write multiple corresponding tags.

Comment: Otherwise, I would suggest a Digital Assets Mangagment (DAM) program like [DigiKam](https://www.digikam.org/) or [Darktable](https://www.darktable.org/). They will write more complete metadata that will be the most future proof.